# Mistake in Calculating Specificity for CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to experiment with CSS.

Here's my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJxrdE

Here's the html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="first">
      <strong class="carrot">C</strong>ascading
      <strong class="spinach">S</strong>tyle
      <strong class="spinach">S</strong>heets
    </p>
    <p id="second">
      <strong>C</strong>ascading
      <strong>S</strong>tyle
      <strong>S</strong>heets
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS

```
p {color: blue; }
strong {color : red;text-decoration: underline;}
.carrot {color:orange;}
.spinach {color:green;}
#first {font-style:italic;color:brown;}
#second {color:blue;}
```

I'm not understanding why the first line is not completely brown. I thought id (#first) have more precedence than classes (.carrot).

I tried calculating the specificity from http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/
. So .carrot has [0,0,1,0] and #first has [0,1,0,0]. I'm not sure what's going on.

Originally, I thought child styles override parent styles but I'm getting conflicting answers on that.

Comment: .spinach {color:green;} class is applied in  <strong class="spinach">S</strong>tyle if you want first line completely brown then you need to remove that class form first line where it's used

Comment: and also the class="carrot" is applied there

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules apply to the specific elements specified by the selectors. They do not somehow magically reach down and affect children. However, some properties (not all) are **inherited*, meaning that in the absence of any specific styling, the property value will be taken from the parent. `color` is one such inherited property.

Your brown rule applies to the `#first` element, but not to children.
The children **might** be styled with the parent color, since color is an **inherited** property, but in this case, you've styled them directly, so no inheritance happens.

To clarify, the high specificity of the id selector **does** pretty much guarantee that the `#first` element will be brown (assuming there's no other rule with an `!important`, for example). But that high specificity has nothing to do with computing the result of the cascade on the children. The children find their own style, and inherit the parent style for color only if they have none of their own. To put it a different way, a high specificity on the parent selector does not make its downward inheritance "stronger" such that would override a setting on a child. Inheritance is neither strong, nor weak, nor important. It's just a behavior that takes place when a child property has the value `inherit` (by default, such as is the case with `color`, or explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting specific elements with the class selectors hence the cascade is overwritten.

To get a better idea target the elements specifically.

```
#first .spinach {
  color: brown;
}
```

http://codepen.io/stenmuchow/pen/rVdMjR

Answer (score 0):

You're also applying styles to the children of `p#first` (`.carrot` and `.spinach`). If you'd want everything on the first line to be brown you could to something like this:

```
#first,
#first strong{
    color: brown;
}
```

And that's just one way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Like for like, an id is more specific than a class. So if you have an id and a class on the same element, the id will "win".

However, in your example the carrot and spinach classes are more specific because they are referring directly to the `strong` elements

If you think about it, id is more specific than class in css because there could be many elements with the same class, but only one with that id. That doesn't follow for child elements, and your code is a good example of why. When you style an element directly with a class, that's more specific than styling its ancestor by id.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at it step by step, CSS applies the brown color first to the whole div then comes into the div and finds the `carrot` class.

It applies the corresponding css, even if it is inside a block defined with another color.

Meaning of `#` selector having more priority over `.` selector:

If you use a div say:

```
<div class="carrot" id="first">Something</div>
```

Now CSS will give priority to the `#` selector and make it brown.

This is how CSS works..

Since `carrot` is a child doesnt have any other id, it has more priority over its parent with a `#` selector applied
By default it would be inherited, but since u defined a class and changed its color, it takess the specified color instead of the parent color.